# Rails | IP spoofing attack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ip

lately I have received such an error on ruby on rails, but do not know what it means. Any help well appreciated!

```
ERROR: Failed to generate exception summary:

ActionView::Template::Error: IP spoofing attack?! HTTP_CLIENT_IP="172.17.3.20" HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR="79.170.168.251"
```

**EDIT:**
I have such a function in the `application controller`

```
before_filter :ensure_domain

  APP_DOMAIN = 'www.mysite.com'

  def ensure_domain
    if request.env['HTTP_HOST'] != APP_DOMAIN && Rails.env.production?
      #HTTP 301 is a "permanent" redirect
      redirect_to "https://#{APP_DOMAIN}#{request.path}", :status => 301

    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're actually doing IP-based authorization, you can likely ignore this. All that this message is telling you is that the IP that the request is coming from is different than the IP that's passed in the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` header, which doesn't necessarily mean that it's a spoof. There are plenty of legitimate reasons for this, so it's generally okay to simply disable the spoof check by setting `config.action_dispatch.ip_spoofing_check = false`